# Can i access an EKS cluster , if i don't have access to iam user that created it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cli, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

An AWS admin , created an IAM user , and that user created an EKS cluster. Now , we don't have access to that IAM user.

If , we try to execute , kubectl , commands on that EKS cluster from a new IAM user that has admin level permissions, we still get "You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)" error.

How can i access that EKS cluster , if i no longer have access to the IAM user that created it ?

Comment: What does "no longer have access" mean? You deleted it? You don't even know what the name of the User was? Do you have CloudTrail turned on for this account?

Comment: Yes, we don't the name of the user, and we didn't have cloud trail enabled at that time.

Comment: What about CloudWatch logging, is that turned on for the cluster? Actually, let's step back -- what have you already tried that is not working for you, so we don't go back-and-forth? _Don't put that info in the comments, [edit your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1065141/edit) to include the attempts and their outcomes_